# using svg as react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

i m trying to use SVG with react, but i can t.i tried some solution, result i didn't find why i get this error:

```
InvalidCharacterError
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<svg>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,227.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<
```

if there anyone who can help me i will be very thankful.
example of the code in codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-in-react-r3g6l?file=/index.js

Comment: You need to include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I usually do:

Visit https://react-svgr.com/playground/ and paste in your SVG and it will transform the SVG into React component. It lets you pass SVG attributes as props.

You may check out its original library - [svgr](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr) for other usages.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the img tag

```
import Logo from "./Logo.svg
<img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: thank you for your response , so how can u change the color of the svg ?

Comment: I see that on the sandbox you have react and react-dom version 16.0.0. have you tried updating to 16.4 or above?

Answer (score 0):

"As part of features added to the new version of create-react-app (v2), we can now import SVGs as React components."

Check this article for more options:
[using-svg-icons-components-in-react](https://blog.lftechnology.com/using-svg-icons-components-in-react-44fbe8e5f91)

*Edit: to change the color of the svg, use the 'fill' propery in CSS. You can add id or class inside your svg to select it.

```
fill: red;
```

Comment: thank u man about ur explication , currently i m using react boilerpate not create react app